# In GNU screen program, can you go back by n-number of lines, and scroll forward from there?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Once I'm in the Copy Mode, how do I go back 500 lines, so that I can start scrolling forward from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you're in scrollback/copy mode you can use vi-style number prefixes to adjust the amount of scroll/copy you apply.

Example for 100 lines:

- Enter scrollback/copy mode: <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
- Up 100 lines: <kbd>100</kbd><kbd>Ctrl u</kbd>

You can see this documented in `man screen`, under the section for `copy`:

> Enter copy/scrollback mode. This allows you to copy text from the current window and its history into the paste buffer. In this mode a vi-like `full screen editor' is active. The editor's movement keys are […]

and then slightly further down,

> **`C-u`** and **`C-d`** scroll  the  display  up/down  by  the specified amount of lines while preserving the cursor  position.

In the documentation the **`C`** character represents the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, so **`C-u`** could be written <kbd>Ctrl u</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

From the [screen(1) man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen), in the "**copy**" section:

> **C-u** and **C-d** scroll the display up/down by the specified amount of
> lines while preserving the cursor position.